# Setting a GPIO port for an accurate time duration with Python

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, python-3

I am trying to set a GPIO port to LOW for `n` seconds and set it to HIGH afterwards.

The problem is that it's not at all accurate. It varies between a small number of seconds to 2*n or even more.

```
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)
time.sleep(n)
GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)
```

I understand that I can't expect a highly accurate interval but a random number is still weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have should be fine.

I'd expect the resulting sleep to be within 1% of **n** the majority of the time (getting more accurate for larger values of **n**).

If you are seeing 2 times **n** it suggests something like:

1. your system is exceptionally busy
2. or the circuit you are driving has a large amount of capacitance to overcome
3. or some other program is affecting the outcome. E.g. if you are using GPIO 4 (pin 7) the 1-wire bus may be enabled.